# Why should we choose the branch cut along the negative real axis for the function $\sqrt z$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Typically, we construct the branch cut for $f(z) = \sqrt z$ along the negative real axis, i.e., if $z = re^{i \theta}$ then $-\pi < \theta < \pi$. I understand that technically all we need is a branch cut that starts at the origin and extends to infinity: in fact, a diagonal line would work just as well. However, my professor said we don't want to set the branch cut to be along the positive real axis would be a mistake--why is this the case?

Note: the context is finding the poles and singularities of the function $f(z) = \frac{\sqrt z - 1}{z - 1}$, so constructing a branch cut is required here to proceed.

Comment: Probably because the positive real axis is where the square root function is viewed as "extended from" so as much as possible you might want to avoid making those points into singularities.  (On the other hand, if you are using complex analysis to integrate a function involving $\sqrt{x}$ on $[0, \infty)$, then integrating along a "keyhole" contour with the positive real axis being "where the key would fit", and using $\sqrt{z}$ with branch cut along the positive real axis, might be just what that problem calls for.)

Comment: any path, starting from zero and going to complex infinity without crossing, could define a branch cut. The branch cut on the negative real line is just because its easier to work with in the majority of cases, but depending of the thing you are trying to do maybe you choose a different branch cut, or no branch cut at all!! In this later case you would work in a Riemann surface